# Not allowing \ through regular expression

Tags: regex

I have created the below regular expression:

```
"format":"^[^/]*$"
```

To not allow forward slash and it works. I also doesn't have to allow forward slash. How can I modify this regular expression.

I tried the below one but it doesn't work:

```
"format":"^[^/\\]*$"
```

Answer (score 2):

The backslash is a special character in regular expressions. That's why you need to escape it with another backslash, so it loses its special meaning (don't copy it into your code yet, look below):

```
"format":"^[^/\\]*$"
```

If your programming language also uses backslashes for escaping, you might need to apply 4 backslashes: First, they are parsed by the compiler, and later, the regex engine will process them another time.

```
"format":"^[^/\\\\]*$"
```